# Node.js, Typescript - How to get file path from multer.js?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, typescript, file-upload, multer

everyone.

I am trying to get filelocation from multer.js so that I can save it inside a database.

What I am trying to do, I have an app, the user can write a post - he can write a title, description and attach a photo. Now when the user creates a new post the post gets created and saved into the database, the photo gets uploaded to the server under the /uploads directory.

However I can't figure out how to save the location of this photo into the database.

The tutorial I am folowing is using not using TypeScript (I am using TypeScript), and he is getting the file path with this

```
image: req.file.path,
```

,but I can't do it as I getting getting data from request like so.

```
const { title, description, creator_id, creator_name } = req.body;
```

This is my Multer middleware saved in middleware_file_upload.ts

```
import multer from "multer";
import { v1 } from 'uuid';

const MIME_TYPE_MAP: any = {
    'image/png' : 'png',
    'image/jpg' : 'jpg',
    'image/jpeg' : 'jpeg',
}

export const fileUpload = multer({
    limits: {fileSize: 500000},
    storage: multer.diskStorage({
        destination: (req: any, file: any, callback: any) => {
            callback(null, 'uploads')

        },
        filename: (req: any, file, callback: any) => {
            const extension = MIME_TYPE_MAP[file.mimetype];
            callback(null, v1() + '.' + extension );
        }
        
    }),
    fileFilter: (req: any, file: any, callback: any) => {
        const isValid = !!MIME_TYPE_MAP[file.mimetype];
        let error = isValid ? null : new Error('Invalid mime type !');
        callback(error, isValid);
    }
});
```

this is my route that is saved inside the routes_POSTS.ts file

```
import express from "express";
import { createNewPost, deletePost, getPostByID, getPostsByUserId, getPosts } from '../controllers/controller_POSTS';
import { check } from 'express-validator';
import { fileUpload } from "../middleware/middleware_file_upload";

export const route = express.Router();


route.get('/:postID', getPostByID);
route.get('/user/:userID', getPostsByUserId);

route.post('/', 
    fileUpload.single('image'),
    [
        check('title').not().isEmpty(),
        check('description').not().isEmpty(),
        check('creator_id').not().isEmpty()
    ], 
    createNewPost);
route.delete('/:postID', deletePost)
```

and this is my createNewPost function saved inside controller_POSTS.ts

```
export const createNewPost = async (req: Request, res: Response, next: NextFunction) => {

    const errors = validationResult(req);
    if(!errors.isEmpty()){
        const error = {
            message: "Error invalid POST request",
            code: 422
        }
        throw next(error);
    }

    const { title, description, creator_id, creator_name } = req.body;

    const newPost = new POST({
        title: title,
        description: description,
        image: req.file.path, //THIS WHER I WANT TO SAVE THE PHOTO PATH LOCATION
        creator_id: creator_id,
        creator_name: creator_name,
    });

    let user: any;
    try {
        user = await USER.findById(creator_id);
    } catch (err) {
        const error = {
            message: "Creating new post failed, try again !",
            code: 500
        }
        return next(error);
    }

    if(!user){
        const error = {
            message: "User couldn't be found by id !",
            code: 404
        };
        return next(error);
    }

    try{
        //FOR WEB BASED MONGO DB
        /*
        const session = await mongoose.startSession();
        session.startTransaction();
        await newPost.save({session: session});

        user.posts.push(newPost); //SAVE POST INTO USER
        await user.save({session: session});
        await session.commitTransaction();
        */

        //FOR LOCAL MONGODB
        await newPost.save();
        user.posts.push(newPost); //SAVE POST INTO USER
        await user.save();

    }catch (err){
        const error = {
            message: "Creating new post failed in sessions, try again !",
            code: 500
        }
        console.log(err);
        return next(error);
    }

    res.status(201).json({post: newPost});

};
```